# QtCreator using MinGW cannot find std::shared_pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, qt-creator, shared-ptr

I just installed QtCreator (using MinGW) on Ubuntu RR, from the Ubuntu Software Center. I have some code that uses features from C++11, specifically:

Strongly typed enums - i.e.: enum class Color {RED, GREEN, BLUE}

std::shared_ptr type, included in memory.h .

This code does not use Qt at all. It is a simple console app, and it compiles and runs fine using CodeBlocks/MinGW and CodeLite/MinGW, with the C++ 11 compiler directive enabled.

When I try to build a project from the same code in QtCreator, (simple C++ console project in QtCreator) I get a warning that the strongly typed enum requires C++11, which is enabled by default. And the compiler does not recognize the shared_ptr type at all - cannot compile.

What is wrong? Is there another compiler option I need to set? The error message seems to indicate that C++11 is enabled by default. Something else? I am new to QtCreator - cannot even find where to set the compiler flags and remove the warning about enums. Where are those settings?

**Most importantly: What do I need to do so that the compiler will recognized the std::shared_ptr type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the right inclusion is

```
#include <memory>
```

and you are supposed to add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

in your `.pro` file to make c++11 work.

edit: with compilers older than `gcc 4.7` you should use the `c++0x` value for that flag.

Comment: The include I already had - it does build fine in other IDE's and the problem with QtCreator was not with the header style - I'm using **#include <memory>** . I just needed to add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 to the .pro file and it built and ran fine.